# Why does this jquery not fire the first droppable event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

```
$(".profile_icon").liveDraggable({ 
        start: function(event, ui){
            $("#team_deletezone").show();
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $("#team_deletezone").fadeOut();
        },
        containment: 'document',
       helper: 'clone',
       opacity: 0.70,
       zIndex:10000,
       appendTo: "body"
});
```

So the item drags and then just doesn't do anything. On the second drop it fires properly?

When the item is dropped it should give a JS `alert();`

Check out the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xeUE/1/)

Comment: can you post a working sample here?

Comment: Updated. :) http://jsfiddle.net/4xeUE/

Comment: As in first drag and drop works with no issue? I'm using chrome too...

Comment: @Linas the drop should cause an alert(); did it do this for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `liveDroppable` to `droppable` and it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2CXt/):

```
 $("#team_deletezone").droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
           alert("This Worked!");
        }
    });
```